# Read long-running PHP process client side

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io, ratchet

I want to read a long-running php process that will return data when a criterion is met.

From my research, I have came across:

- Long polling
- Sockets (socket.io & node.js)
- Ratchet

I am struggling to understand & apply an implementation of my problem. I have the following loop in PHP:

```
public function store(ClientImpl $a)
{
    $request = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all();
    $originateMsg = new OriginateAction('Local/' . $request['agent'] . '@auto-answer');
    $originateMsg->setContext('G-Outgoing');
    $originateMsg->setPriority('1');
    $originateMsg->setExtension($request['dial']);
    $a->send($originateMsg);

    while(true) {
        if( $a->process() ) break;
        usleep(1000);
    }

    $a->close();

    echo 'OK';
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
}
```

`$a->process()` calls the following method:

```
/**
 * Main processing loop. Also called from send(), you should call this in
 * your own application in order to continue reading events and responses
 * from ami. 
 */
public function process()
{
    $msgs = $this->getMessages();
    foreach ($msgs as $aMsg) {
        if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
            $this->_logger->debug(
                '------ Received: ------ ' . "\n" . $aMsg . "\n\n"
            );
        }
        $resPos = strpos($aMsg, 'Response:');
        $evePos = strpos($aMsg, 'Event:');
        if (($resPos !== false) && (($resPos < $evePos) || $evePos === false)) {
            $response = $this->_messageToResponse($aMsg);
            $this->_incomingQueue[$response->getActionId()] = $response;
        } else if ($evePos !== false) {
            $event = $this->_messageToEvent($aMsg);
            $response = $this->findResponse($event);
            if ($response === false || $response->isComplete()) {
                $this->dispatch($event);
            } else {
                $response->addEvent($event);
            }
        } else {
            // broken ami.. sending a response with events without
            // Event and ActionId
            $bMsg = 'Event: ResponseEvent' . "\r\n";
            $bMsg .= 'ActionId: ' . $this->_lastActionId . "\r\n" . $aMsg;
            $event = $this->_messageToEvent($bMsg);
            $response = $this->findResponse($event);
            $response->addEvent($event);
        }
        if ($this->_logger->isDebugEnabled()) {
            $this->_logger->debug('----------------');
        }
    }
}
```

`$a->process()` then stacks up Event messages, to read these I create an implementation of `IEventListener` which is also called 'behind the scenes' when `$a->process()` is called.

```
class VoipEventStart implements IEventListener
{
    public function handle(EventMessage $event)
    {
        $a = $event->getKeys();

        if( ($a['event'] == "Hangup" || $a['event'] == "HangupRequest") && strpos($a['channel'], 'SIP/') !== FALSE)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The process method reads events from an Asterisk PBX system while a user is on an active call. This means the process loop will last as long as the call lasts.

How would I execute this client-side without the browser looking like it is loading/waiting?

Comment: Do you mean simple ajax?

Comment: What does $a->process() do? How long does it run? What does it return?

Comment: I don't see process() returning anything. But the loop in your example would break/stop when process() returns truthy.

Comment: @marekful Sorry, I forgot to add a class. `VoIPEventStart` returns true on HangUp.

Comment: I see your update. So is it the case that process() always returns immediatelly (or relatively fast) either true or false and you want to detect from client side when it returned true w/o blocking the client agent?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: How is your long running script called?

Comment: @DanFromGermany As it stands, A simple form executes the `store` method.

Comment: @jakehallas that means that you probably have a timeout anyways. You should start long processing scripts from serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Server Sent Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events) or some socket implementation but for simplest probably a long-poll strategy would work out well enough.

For that, send a plain AJAX request from the client and make server only return when the criterion is met. It could be as simple as changing the server side code as follows:

```
while(true) {
    if( $a->process() ) break;
    usleep(1000);
}
echo 'OK';
ob_end_flush();
flush();
```

And the client should send a simple GET request to the PHP file that starts the above loop. This way when a response comes back to this request, you know process() return true.

The client code could look something like this:

```
<div>Call status: <span id="status">In call</span></div>
<script>
  $.get('/check_call_status.php?callerId=123', function(response) {
    if(response === 'OK') {
      $('#staus').html('finished');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Of course, this could be more sophisticated to deal with timeouts. E.g. if there's no response to the long-poll request for a given time period, restart it - i.e. abort the request and send it again to avoid client or server timeouts.

Comment: I've tried this & timeouts seem to be the big issue. If the call lasts longer than the timeout period the Ajax call fails. I cannot re-request this because it depends on the specific implementation of $a (see updated `store` method.) meaning everytime I re-request, I would get a new implementation. What would you advise?

Comment: Than it sounds like a design flaw. There must some kind of identifier for a caller or for an existing call. Using that, it should be possible to return to the event status checker loop. If the call doesn't exist any more (e.g. $a->close() was called) you should be able to detect that, and return immediately.

Comment: Aborting the AJAX request will execute its `anobort` callback so it shouldn't update the client side with false information. It is a good practice when employing long-polling to abort the request before any timeout would occur and immediately restart it.

Comment: Sorry about the late response. It was indeed a design flaw, long-polling is now a success. Thank you very much!